# using twistd to run a twisted application but script run twice

Tags: python, twisted, twistd

sample code here

```
# main.py
from twisted.application import service, internet

application = service.Application("x")
service.IProcess(application).processName = "x"

print "some log...."
```

if I run this main.py with:

```
twistd -y main.py
```

I got 2 "some log...." lines.

If this code run twice?

[image]

Comment: for me it run once..
can you reproduce it with this code ?

Comment: I add a pic here. I think maybe the log print twice if I using print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "process name" feature you're using works by re-executing the process with a new `argv[0]`.  There is no completely reliable way to save an arbitrary object (like the Application) across this process re-execution.  This means that the .py file has to be re-evaluated in the new process to recreate the Application object so twistd knows what you want it to do.

Comment: yes! I removed service.IProcess(application).processName = "x" and it print one line log now.But it is still a little weird

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [`setproctitle`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setproctitle) rather than `twistd`'s built-in process title feature.  (For that matter, maybe `twistd` should just use it if it's available...)